# Can't add following text to database but works with other texts

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can't add the below text to database. Column is longtext type.

```
$sql = $first."SET title='".$news_title."', summary='".$news_summary."', description='".$news_description."', category_id='".$news_category."', status='".$news_status."', reporter_id='".$news_reporter."', location='".$news_location."', news_date='".$news_date."', added_by='".$news_adder."'".$last;
```

The sql works well with other texts longer than this:

*Oct 13, 2017-Hong Kong have posted a 195-run target against Nepal during the ICC World Cricket League Championship at Mission Road Ground, Mong Kok on Friday.
Hong Kong, who were invited to bat first, were bundled out for 194 runs
Nepal's leg spinner Sandeep Lamichhane claimed three wickets while Basanta Regmi and Karan KC grabbed two wickets each and Sushan Bhari claimed one wicket.
JJ Atkinson for scored highest 76 runs off 117 balls hitting nine fours and a six.
Similarly, Tanwir Afzal contributed 38 runs off 42 balls that included three boundaries and three sixes.
Likewise, skipper Babar Hayat scored 29 runs off 26 balls with the help of two fours and a six.
ICC World Cricket League Championship: Nepal playing against Hong Kong 
Nepal are playing against Hong Kong in their must-win matches of the ICC World Cricket League Championship at Mission Road Ground, Mong Kok on Friday.
Nepal won the toss and decided to field first. Hong Kong have already lost seven wickets.
This is the last match of the sixth round.
Nepal, who have eight points from 10 matches, are sixth in the standing, while Hong Kong are fifth with 11 points.
Only the top four teams of the Championship will secure their berth for the 2018 ICC World Cup Qualifiers to be held in Zimbabwe.
Nepal last played Hong Kong in the ACC Emerging Teams Cup in Bangladesh where half centuries from Gyanendra Malla and Dipendra Singh Airee saw them win the match by seven wickets.
Sharad Bheswakar from Nepal will miss the matches against Hong Kong on Friday and Sunday due to illness.
Vesawkar is the second highest scorer for Nepal in the WCLC having made 321 runs from 10 innings.
Only skipper Paras Khadka (352) has score more than Vesawkar in the tournament.
Naresh Budhayer, who was named reserved, has been called up in place for Vesawkar and has already left for Hongkong*

Comment: Any error coming or what?

Comment: What error do you have?Can you give database structure?

Comment: Could be due to a) not escaping the text (194 runs Nepal's leg spinner S) note the apostrophe and b) field not set large enough to hold all of the data

Comment: @Yojan, whee is your code ?

Comment: can we see your SQL/PDO query?

Comment: The query doesn't executes with this text only. Works fine with other texts

Answer (score 0):

3rd line of the text "Nepal's leg". Your query escapes there. Replace ' with something else.